# Read python list correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have defined a function that takes in a list like this

```
arr = ['C','D','E','I','M']
```

I have another function that produces a similar kind of list, the function is:

```
def tree_count(arr):
    feat = ['2','2','2','2','0']
    feat_2 = []
    dictionary = dict(zip(arr, feat))
    print('dic',dictionary)
    feat_2.append([k for k,v in dictionary.items() if v=='2'])

    newarr = str(feat_2)[1:-1]
    print(newarr)
```

This outputs the correct result that I want, i.e:

```
['C','D','E','I']
```

But the problem is, when I use this list in another function, its values should be read as `C,D,E,I` . But instead when I print this, the bracket [ and ' are included as result:

```
for i in newarr:
   print(i)
```

The printed result is : `[ ' C '`, and so on for each line. I want to get rid of `[ '`.  How do I solve this?

Comment: because it is no longer a *list*, you *made it a string:* `newarr = str(feat_2)[1:-1]`

Comment: I tried using : newarr = list(str(feat_2)[1:-1]) , the result I get is              ['[', "'", 'C', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'D', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'E', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'I', "'", ']']
what should I do? I am new to python

Comment: why are you using `str(feat_2)`? I think you can do perfectly fine without it.

Comment: why are you using `str`??

Comment: @MohsinBukhari  The feat_2 has extra brackets , it is printed as      [['C', 'D', 'E', 'I']] , to remove the extra outer brackets, I used str(feat_2)[1:-1] , without str it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your function return the dictionary rather than just printing it:

```
def tree_count(arr):
    feat = ['2','2','2','2','0']
    dictionary = dict(zip(arr, feat))
    dictionary = [k for k in dictionary if dictionary[k] == '2']
    return dictionary
```

For instance,

```
$ results = tree_count(['C','D','E','I','M'])
$ print(results)
['I', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Pretty-printing is then fairly straightforward:

```
$ print("\n".join(results))
I
C
D
E
```

... or if you just want `,`:

```
$ print(", ".join(results))
I, C, D, E
```

Comment: (I'm not a big `zip` guru, so let me know if I misunderstood your intention with your code.)

Comment: The dictionary is this: dic {'C': '2', 'D': '2', 'E': '2', 'I': '2', 'M': '0'}  I want an array of keys whose value is 2. So the result needs to be an array ['C','D','E','I']

Comment: Thank You :). That is exactly what I was trying

Answer (score 2):

For some reason you are using `str()` on the array, this is what causes the square brackets from array to appear in the `print` statement.
See if the following methods suit you:

```
print(arr) # ['C','D','E','I'] - the array itself

print(str(arr)) # "['C', 'D', 'E', 'I']" - the array as string literal

print(''.join(arr)) # 'CDEI' - array contents as string with no spaces

print(' '.join(arr)) # 'C D E I' - array contents as string with spaces
```